# How to use externaltemplate parameters in compilation time

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have the following code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <array>

    template <class T, size_t dims> class dataType { 
        public:
            void show() {
                t_.show();
                std::cout << dims << " dimensions" << std::endl;            
            }
        private:
            T t_;
};


    class heapType {
        public:
            void show() {
                std::cout << "This is heapType class" << std::endl; 
            }
};

    class dataClass {
        public:
            void show() {
                std::cout << "This is dataClass class" << std::endl; 
            }
};

    template < class data_t, class heap_t> class algorithmType {

public:
            void showDataType () {
                mydata_.show();
            }

            void showHeapType () {
                myheap_.show();
            }

            void showN() {
                std::cout << "I want to use n here" << std::endl;
            }

    private:
        data_t mydata_;
        heap_t myheap_;
        std::array<int,n> myArray; //Also want to use n here.
};


    int main (void) {

        constexpr int n = 2;
        algorithmType<dataType<dataClass,n>, heapType> myAlgorithm;

        myAlgorithm.showDataType();
        myAlgorithm.showHeapType();
        myAlgorithm.showN();
    }
```

The output, as expected is:

```
This is dataClass class
2 dimensions
This is heapType class
I want to use n here
```

I want to use the `dims` template parameter of `dataType` in `algorithmType` (`showN()` method, declared as `n` in the main) in compilation time. The real code will perform loops and create std::arrays depending on this parameter so I want it to be known in compilation time in order to let the compiler do its optimizations. Is it possible to do that?

I have no restrictions to change the definitions of the classes, but I would like to keep them as close as they are now as possible.

Thank you!

**EDIT:** I have added the line `std::array<int,n> myArray; //Also want to use n here.` in the `algorithmType` private members. Assuming that I have adopted the solution given by @kcm1700, how can I declare that array size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the template argument as follwing code.

```
template <class T, size_t dims> class dataType { 
public:
    static constexpr size_t n = dims;
...
```

Using it in showN() is trivial, `data_t::n`.

Or you can make a constexpr function for the size.

```
template <class T, size_t dims> class dataType { 
public:
    constexpr size_t size() const { return dims; }
...
```

Comment: Thank you! that works! However, I wonder if this is a good solution from a style point of view.

Comment: Actually I prefer creating a constexpr function for the size, just like in std::array. I'll add the corresponding example in the answer.

Comment: Thank you, when I saw you answer I was thinking on that option :)

Comment: Please, read the edit. I have added `std::array<int,n> myArray; //Also want to use n here.` as a private member of `algorithmType`. I forgot to do it before, sorry. How can I define that array size? Can I only define it in the corresponding method `algorithmType::showN()` or can I create that array somehow?

Comment: In this case, you'll have to use 'static' member function or field in order to get dims without an instance of the dataType class. But why would you want the dims without an instance?

Comment: `algorithmType` in my case is an algorithm which works for `dims` dimensions. Therefore, the most efficient way I found is to declare the arrays as class members since they are used just in 1 method of the class but this method is called thousands of times. I need to define the size of the arrays in compilation time. There will be an instance of `algorithmType` and an instance of `dataType` that will be passed later in a function. Actually, it is `myAlgorithm::setDataType(data_t * d)`.

Comment: I solved it this way:

`static constexpr size_t ndims = data_t::getDims();`
`std::array<int, ndims> myArray;`

while `dataType::getDims()` is also static. Is this a good design?

Comment: Assuming the function version, prepend `static` to `size()` function definition. `std::array<int, data_t::size()> myArray;` will work.

Comment: perfect, I got it! I'm sorry the question got that messed up. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
template <class T, size_t dims>
class dataType { 
public:
    constexpr size_t getDims() { return dims; }
    ...
}
```

Then use it like that

```
template < class data_t, class heap_t>
class algorithmType {
public:
    ...
    void test() {
        int data[mydata_.getDims()];
        data[0] = 5;
        std::cout << data[0] << std::endl;
    }
};
```